# Confused on "pass by reference" in C and when to use an & or *

Tags: c, pointers, embedded, pass-by-reference

I'm not as knowledgeable in C as I thought I was, but can anyone explain to me what I'm doing wrong here ? I am writing a program for an embedded system using a Texas Instruments microcontroller using UARTS (an asynchronous receiver transmitter on the microcontroller). UART libraries are usually included when I'm building a project.

Anyway, here is my issue: I have 4 functions that just prints a string to the console and my code compiles, but it gives me warnings and not compilation errors.

```
void foward(unsigned char *command) {
    UARTPutString(UART_BASE, &command);
}

void reverse(unsigned char *command) {
    UARTPutString(UART_BASE, &command);
}

void left(unsigned char *command) {
    UARTPutString(UART_BASE, &command);
}

void right(unsigned char *command) {
    UARTPutString(UART_BASE, &command);
}
```

My issue mainly lines with when to use a pointer in the simplest sense. The reason why I used a pointer for char* command is because the imported library was written like that, but I have no idea why we have to use a char pointer. And what do you put as the second argument in:

```
UARTPutString(UART_BASE, &command);
```

When do I use &, or * ? I know pointers point to the memory address of something, but it's not clicking to me on when I need to use *, &, and so forth when using it as parameters for a function.

This warning is mentioned 21 times for some reason:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
#169-D argument of type "unsigned char **" is incompatible with parameter of type "unsigned char *" uartconsole.c   /Command_Line_Interface line 82 C/C++ Problem
```

Thank for the help !

Comment: Why do you think you need to pass this by reference? That's normally used only when the function needs to modify the caller's variable.

Comment: If the function just writes the string to the UART, it doesn't need to be passed by reference.

Comment: What is the signature of the `UARTPutString()` function? The type of `&command` is `char **` since `command` is `char *`.

Comment: Please post the exact error message.

Comment: @Barmar Sorry about that,I forgot the warnings.This warning is repeated 21 times: Description Resource Path Location Type
#169-D argument of type "unsigned char **" is incompatible with parameter of type "unsigned char *" uartconsole.c /Command_Line_Interface line 82 C/C++ Problem

Comment: C doesn’t support pass by reference, only pass by value.

Comment: This is very fundamental stuff, so I'd recommend finding a good C book and first read the chapter about pointers, then the chapter about string handling, in that order. Once you've gotten the hang of that, search & study the term "const correctness". Also, forget about "it gives me warnings and not compilation errors" - you should have zero warnings, warnings are by no means less severe than errors. Either is an indication of a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write:

```
UARTPutString(UART_BASE, command);
```

Your `command` is a pointer (i.e., a variable holding an address) to a character array.

When writing `&command` you take the address of `command`. The type of the `&command` expression is therefore the address of a pointer `unsigned char **`, which is what the compiler is complaining about.

So that warning is telling you the compiler is expecting just `unsigned char *` as the second argument of `UARTPutString()`, which is the type of `command`.

What is confusing about `*` in C is that its 'meaning' depends on the place where it's used. In a variable declaration it says that the variable is a pointer. While used in an expression, for example if you would write `*command = 0;`, it dereferences the pointer; the opposite of when `*` is used in a declaration.

There's a lot more to say about this and I suggest you read relevant sections of the [C-FAQ](http://c-faq.com).

Good luck. C is a very nice language and worth putting the effort in.

Answer (score 2):

The 2nd argument to `UARTPutString()` is supposed to be a string, which is a `char *` value -- a string is a pointer to a sequence of characters.

`command` is declared to be `char *`, so you should just pass that directly. Adding `&` creates a pointer to a pointer, which is `char **`, and incompatible with `char *`.

```
UARTPutString(UART_BASE, command);
```

You use `&` before a variable when you need to pass the variable by reference. This is usually done if the function needs to modify the variable's value. It may also be used for large structure variables, to avoid making a copy of the variable when passing it to the function.